# Trying to learn .ajax() - my json keeps throwing error: "undefined" - what am I doing?

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have no idea why my json object is returning undefined.  I am not seeing anything syntactically wrong with it in my JSON tools, but I have a feeling that there must be something wrong with how I am structuring it.

I want to start making a zombie game, but the first step for me is understanding how to pass the data which I have created into the front end.  This is where I have been hoping to implement ajax for class, but my console is sending me an error: "undefined"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'dummy_json.json',
                    data : { load : true},
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 1000,
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log("HOLY SHIT ZOMBIES!");
                        console.log(textStatus + " is " + errorThrown);
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $("body").append(data); // really basic append, more to come.
                    }
                });
            });
```

And below are the contents of the dummy_json.json file, which contains my hand written zombie quest data.  I want to do this from scratch so that I can learn json very well. Eventually I will write the php that extracts this from db and converts to json for the view to consume:

```
    { id : 0, bulletinquest : {
    items : [{
        zombie0 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "JKL",
            "zombiename" : " - Black",
            "genomeid" : "4778931",
            "reward" : "100",
            "imageName" : "4778931.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie1 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "JKL",
            "zombiename" : " - White",
            "genomeid" : "4779436",
            "reward" : "100",
            "imageName" : "4779436.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie2 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "JKL",
            "zombiename" : " II - Gray",
            "genomeid" : "6900326",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "6900326.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie3 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "JKL",
            "zombiename" : " II - White",
            "genomeid" : "7009803",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "7009803.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie4 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "JKL",
            "zombiename" : " III - Red",
            "genomeid" : "5715837",
            "reward" : "100",
            "imageName" : "5715837.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie5 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "GHI",
            "zombiename" : " II - Gray",
            "genomeid" : "6941414",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "6941414.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie6 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "GHI",
            "zombiename" : " II - White",
            "genomeid" : "6930804",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "6930804.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie7 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " - Blue",
            "genomeid" : "5597904",
            "reward" : "200",
            "imageName" : "5597904.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie8 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " III (Slow Walker) - Blue",
            "genomeid" : "5715212",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "5715212.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie9 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " III (Slow Walker) - White",
            "genomeid" : "5715328",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "5715328.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie10 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " III (Fast Walker) - White",
            "genomeid" : "6209005",
            "reward" : "200",
            "imageName" : "6209005.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie11 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " III (Fast Walker) - Blue",
            "genomeid" : "6209286",
            "reward" : "200",
            "imageName" : "6209286.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie12 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " II - Gray",
            "genomeid" : "6958754",
            "reward" : "300",
            "imageName" : "6958754.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie13 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " II - White",
            "genomeid" : "6958772",
            "reward" : "300",
            "imageName" : "6958772.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie14 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "ABC",
            "zombiename" : " III - Amber Brown",
            "genomeid" : "6901339",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "6901339.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie15 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "ABC",
            "zombiename" : " III - Black",
            "genomeid" : "6901302",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "6901302.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie16 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "ABC",
            "zombiename" : " III (Slow Walker) - White",
            "genomeid" : "5715328",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "5715328.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie17 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "ABC",
            "zombiename" : " III (Slow Walker) - White",
            "genomeid" : "5716681",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "5716681.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie18 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "ABC",
            "zombiename" : " III (Slow Walker) - Blue",
            "genomeid" : "5717547",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "5717547.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie19 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "ABC",
            "zombiename" : " III (Fast Walker) - White",
            "genomeid" : "5717574",
            "reward" : "200",
            "imageName" : "5717574.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie20 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " III (Fast Walker) - Blue",
            "genomeid" : "5717583",
            "reward" : "200",
            "imageName" : "5717583.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        }
    }],
    bulletinquestType : "iHaveNoIdea",
    bulletinquestAmmount : "500",
    bulletinquestName : "Please help save the animal shelter from being overrun!"
}, id : 1, bulletinquest : {
    name : "FROGGA FETT PROMO WILL EAT YOU",
    items : [{
        zombie0 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "JKL",
            "zombiename" : " - Black",
            "genomeid" : "4778931",
            "reward" : "100",
            "imageName" : "4778931.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie1 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "JKL",
            "zombiename" : " - White",
            "genomeid" : "4779436",
            "reward" : "100",
            "imageName" : "4779436.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie2 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "JKL",
            "zombiename" : " II - Gray",
            "genomeid" : "6900326",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "6900326.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie3 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "JKL",
            "zombiename" : " II - White",
            "genomeid" : "7009803",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "7009803.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie4 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "JKL",
            "zombiename" : " III - Red",
            "genomeid" : "5715837",
            "reward" : "100",
            "imageName" : "5715837.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie5 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "GHI",
            "zombiename" : " II - Gray",
            "genomeid" : "6941414",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "6941414.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie6 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "GHI",
            "zombiename" : " II - White",
            "genomeid" : "6930804",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "6930804.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie7 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " - Blue",
            "genomeid" : "5597904",
            "reward" : "200",
            "imageName" : "5597904.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie8 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " III (Slow Walker) - Blue",
            "genomeid" : "5715212",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "5715212.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie9 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " III (Slow Walker) - White",
            "genomeid" : "5715328",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "5715328.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie10 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " III (Fast Walker) - White",
            "genomeid" : "6209005",
            "reward" : "200",
            "imageName" : "6209005.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie11 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " III (Fast Walker) - Blue",
            "genomeid" : "6209286",
            "reward" : "200",
            "imageName" : "6209286.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie12 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " II - Gray",
            "genomeid" : "6958754",
            "reward" : "300",
            "imageName" : "6958754.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie13 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " II - White",
            "genomeid" : "6958772",
            "reward" : "300",
            "imageName" : "6958772.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie14 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "ABC",
            "zombiename" : " III - Amber Brown",
            "genomeid" : "6901339",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "6901339.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie15 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "ABC",
            "zombiename" : " III - Black",
            "genomeid" : "6901302",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "6901302.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie16 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "ABC",
            "zombiename" : " III (Slow Walker) - White",
            "genomeid" : "5715328",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "5715328.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie17 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "ABC",
            "zombiename" : " III (Slow Walker) - White",
            "genomeid" : "5716681",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "5716681.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie18 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "ABC",
            "zombiename" : " III (Slow Walker) - Blue",
            "genomeid" : "5717547",
            "reward" : "45",
            "imageName" : "5717547.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie19 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "ABC",
            "zombiename" : " III (Fast Walker) - White",
            "genomeid" : "5717574",
            "reward" : "200",
            "imageName" : "5717574.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        },
        zombie20 : {
            "regionoforigin" : "DEF",
            "zombiename" : " III (Fast Walker) - Blue",
            "genomeid" : "5717583",
            "reward" : "200",
            "imageName" : "5717583.png",
            "moreinfo" : "To kill a zombie you must destroy the brain."
        }
    }],
    bulletinquestType : "savior",
    bulletinquestAmmount : "Over 9000",
    bulletinquestName : "Clear the brooklyn tunnel"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  What *exactly* does the error say?  Where is it happening in your code?

Comment: So I'm using both FF and Chrome.  The value of "errorThrown" is "undefined" - basically it thinks that the entire json object is undefined... I was able to rectify this by: `1. I bracketed the entire array. 2. I bracketed the entire contents of each "bulletinquest" array 3. I wrapped the id's in double quotes.`  **The problem I'm having now is that when I try to access the nested _items_ array - console thinks that it is undefined!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's invalid JSON. You need to wrap the whole thing in square brackets to make it an array:

```
[ { id : 0, ... }, 
  { id: 1, ... },
  ...
]
```

Note, to check if JSON is valid, there are plenty of online tools that can help (eg, [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)).  (You'll see there that valid JSON technically requires the keys (`id`, etc) to be wrapped in double-quotes.)

Comment: Woohoo!  It works now.  I did a couple of things based upon your suggestion:
1. I bracketed the entire array.
2. I bracketed the entire contents of each "bulletinquest" array
3. I wrapped the id's in double quotes.

Success.  Thanks dbaseman!

Comment: Are keys not allowed to have the same values EVER in json??  I keep getting "data[index].bulletinrequest.items is undefined." Hm...

Comment: Hmmm.. so I have two bulletinquest arrays... they are each contained within their own array... I can access them with javascript, but I run into an "undefined" error when I drill down to "items"... I am having trouble seeing what the heck is wrong with this array...

Comment: @user1809836 as it's written above, `items` looks problematic.  Should be either an array like `items: [ { zombieName: "Bill" }, { } ]` or an object like `items: { zombie1: { zombieName: "Bill" }, zombie2: { } ]`